# PHP POST not working, what module to enable

Tags: php, post, request

I want to make a PHP POST request from my new VPS server to another IP address. I checked the firewall and everything seemed fine but the request never went to the other IP, so I then tried making the same request with node.js and it went through. The question is, what PHP module/extension do I need to enable to allow php requests with or without curl.

A simple CURL request:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url='http://example.com/';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: You would get more help if you included the code which is not working.

Comment: I really don't understand why I was downvoted, but whatever

Comment: You're missing a single quote at the end of the example.com line

Comment: Your missing a quote off `'http://example.com/;` (Not my downvote, but codeless questions often get downvoted)

Comment: You are right, although that is not the error, I changed the url in order to post the question and forgot to close the quote.